# New DEM tag for TanDEM-X

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I don't have the reputation yet, but can we create a tag for:

TanDEM-X

We have similar tags for Aster and SRTM.

Comment: Is this Twin Satellites not an image format/DEM format? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TanDEM-X

Comment: The tag would be a subclass of "DEM". Just makes following this specific one easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "tandem" and "tanDEM" would be conflated in searches, I agree that a special tag would provide semantic disambiguation.  Currently it is appropriate only for two questions (because tanDEM-X featured prominently in their answers), to which I applied the tag [tandem-x](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tandem-x).

Comment: Thank you for your help!